# JSON RPC in WCF

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf

I have been attempting to find a good implementation of Json rpc in wcf, but I have not had much luck yet.I have found several examples of implementations using jayrock and Json-rpc.net, but I would prefer to work within wcf as much as possible.

Has anyone ever developed a Json rpc server within wcf? If so, could you point me towards some example code or documentation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Nobody? This seems like a reasonable scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It *is* a reasonable scenario. I'm not sure how to do it with WCF, but I think [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) is the way to go. Also from Microsoft.